# How can I improve my listening comprehension?

Tags: vocabulary

I can read Italian pretty well but when it comes to listening I'm lost, unless it's a conversation that I'm actively participating in. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Ti suggerisco di guardare qualche film in italiano, consiglio "La Vita è bella". Poi anche il telegiornale.

Comment: esistono gli audiolibri, cosí puoi leggere anche quello che non capisci mentre li ascolti.. Sono utili in questi casi come anche quando hai poco tempo per (finir di) leggere un romanzo o altro ;) (su youtube trovi qualcosa). Altro consiglio che posso darti è seguire documentari (ad esempio "La storia siamo noi"), reporter (su rai tre) e dibattiti (su la 7) ma quelli seri (intendo non certo Voyager, o Mistero, o altri simili..) che sicuramente troverai anche online. Certo, vi sono i telegiornali anche ma sentire le notizie alle volte è noioso (io preferisco rai news 24)

Comment: Per il resto ti devi abituare a sentire come parla la gente, quindi trascorri piú tempo che puoi in mezzo ad italiani, ascolta canzoni italiane (anche parodie, mi viene in mente Crozza con il suo programma anche), esistono anche cartoni e serie tradotte in italiano... ;)

Comment: @DaG, è opinione personale, certamente! Ho cancellato i due commenti riscrivendo il primo correttamente e in ordine.. :P

Comment: Bene, grazie, @mle.

Comment: You are welcome to join the Italian language group on Facebook: https://www.facebook.com/groups/Italianforbeginners/

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you listen to Italian audio books, maybe by authors you like.
For each new page or part you have listened to, guess what has been said. 
Finally, compare what you've written down with the original text in the book. 
You could also watch Italian television news and do the same as before.

Comment: In addition, sometimes listen to audio while following along in printed text.  This (hypothetically) may strengthen an association between the sound and its spelling.

Comment: Ha, I should have read the Italian comment before repeating it!